# Better biggestPlus algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

The problem is finding the biggest + (plus) in a matrix:

"Given a matrix that contains only the characters '0' and '1', find the biggest plus sign (+) composed of 1s and return its rank. Rank, in this case, indicates the length of the plus sign's edges. In order to be a valid plus sign, the edges must be of equal length."

My current algorithm is below.  Basically it goes through the matrix of size n, three times.  First it goes through it and determines the value of 1s to its left/up.  The second pass determines the value of 1s to its right/down.  The third one compares the 4 matrices generated and finds the minimum value.  The maximum of these values is the answer.

I was wondering how the algorithm can be optimized.  The length of the matrix can go up to 1000x1000.  Is there a way to determine the answer just by going through the matrix once?  If so how could that be done.  Or is there a better approach in determining the answer that is completely different than this one?

```
def biggestPlus(matrix):
    def get_left_up():
        dp_left = [[-1 for _ in row] for row in matrix]
        dp_up = [[ -1 for _ in row ] for row in matrix ]

        for y, row in enumerate(matrix):
            for x, val in enumerate(row):
                if val == '1':
                    #####FOR DP_LEFT
                    if x != 0:
                        dp_left[y][x] = dp_left[y][x-1] + 1
                    else:
                        dp_left[y][x] = 0

                    #####FOR DP_UP
                    if y != 0:
                        dp_up[y][x] = dp_up[y-1][x] + 1
                    else:
                        dp_up[y][x] = 0

        return dp_left, dp_up

    def get_right_down():
        dp_right = [[-1 for _ in row] for row in matrix]
        dp_down = [[-1 for _ in row] for row in matrix]

        for y in range(len(matrix)-1,-1,-1):
            row = matrix[y]
            for x in range(len(row) - 1, -1, -1):
                val = matrix[y][x]
                if val == '1':
                    #####FOR DP_RIGHT
                    if x < len(row)-1:
                        dp_right[y][x] = dp_right[y][x + 1] + 1
                    else:
                        dp_right[y][x] = 0

                    #####FOR DP_DOWN
                    if y < len(matrix)-1:
                        dp_down[y][x] = dp_down[y + 1][x] + 1
                    else:
                        dp_down[y][x] = 0

        return dp_right, dp_down

    def getBiggestPlus(dp_left,dp_up,dp_right,dp_down):
        #####GET MIN OF 4 MATRICES
        result = 0

        for y, row in enumerate(dp_left):
            for x, val in enumerate(row):
                minimum = min(dp_left[y][x],dp_down[y][x],dp_right[y][x],dp_up[y][x])
                result = max(result,minimum)         #####ANSWER IS THE MAX

        return result

    dp_left, dp_up = get_left_up()
    dp_right, dp_down = get_right_down()
    return getBiggestPlus(dp_left,dp_up,dp_right,dp_down)
```

Example input:

```
matrix =   ["0110010",
            "1010101",
            "1111111",
            "0010000",
            "0000000"]
print("Answer:", biggestPlus(matrix))
```

Comment: I guess you should check if your question would be a better fix on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (but if you consider posting your question there make sure to check their help page first to determine if your question is on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

In a square matrix of N rows, a `+` with an edge length *n* must have a horizontal part of length *2n+1*, and that part cannot start above line *n* or below line *N - n*, else the vertical edges won't fit.

This biggest possible `+` can only fit at the very center of the matrix.

I would start scanning the matrix for horizontal lines, and look for matching verticals for them. I'd have a variable *k* for the biggest plus edge I can still potentially find, given the remaining vertical space. I'd start at the middle with *k = N/2*.

On each step, I'd look for a horizontal stretch of `1`s no more than *2k + 1* in length; there can be several in a line. For each of them, I'd look for a matching vertical, scanning the column at the center.

The usual ideas of finding maxima apply; keep the best known result, replace if found a better one. Here it makes sense to stop if *k* becomes less that the best known result, and ignore any horizontal stretches smaller than it, too.

The trick to best performance is to run two scans in parallel, one upwards and one downwards, in lockstep. They can also be run sequentially, but then the algorithm might need to do a full upwards scan, finding e.g. nothing, and then find a large plus in the bottom part, near the middle. With the lockstep execution, the biggest plusses are found fastest.

Coding this is up to you, but the first functions I'd write would be:

```
def find_horizontal_stretches(matrix, line, no_shorter_than=1):  
  """Returns a list of stretches as [(start, length),..],
     each no shorter than indicated.
  """

def has_vertical_stretch(matrix, line, column, size):
  """Returns True iff a column of 1s of given size is present
     at given column, and is centered at given line."""
```